# Absolute Paths beginning with two slashes

Tags: html, path, anchor, absolute-path

I noticed that Wikipedia links pointing to a path on a different Wikipedia subdomain use a link with the following syntax: `//<SERVER_NAME>/<REQUEST_URI>`. For example, a link from a [file page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Stack_Overflow_website_logo.png) to the [file](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Stack_Overflow_website_logo.png) appears (for example) as `//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Stack_Overflow_website_logo.png`. I am familiar with absolute paths (thinking twice about that now) and relative paths and how to use them. However, I have never seen this use. I assume this points to a new server name using the current protocol. Is this correct? And is there an official name (or widely accepted name) for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does using //www.example.com in Javascript chose http/https protocol automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799577/does-using-www-example-com-in-javascript-chose-http-https-protocol-automatical)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network-Path Reference URI / Scheme relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these `//example.com` URIs are called "Scheme Relative" or "Protocol Relative", and there is more information about it at this question:

[Network-Path Reference URI / Scheme relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls)

**EDIT:**

Apparently this might actually be called a "network-path reference" as seen here:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2

Quote:

> A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed
> a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.  A
> relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
> termed an absolute-path reference.  A relative reference that does
> not begin with a slash character is termed a relative-path reference.

Comment: While looking at the question you linked to, I found a link to the RFC document (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). The Internet Society has coined this as a "network-path reference". I had no idea what to type into the Google to find this. Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: Not sure if your edit or my comment came first but thanks. :)

Comment: Haha, I think they came at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely right. A link to `//some/path` is a protocol relative path.

Namely, if you are currently on `http://something.example.com`, a link to `//google.com` would point to `http://google.com`.

If you are currently on `https://something.example.com`, a link to `//google.com` would point to `https://google.com`.

The most common use of this can be seen in the html5 boilerplate.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Kindly google provides its javascript cdn over both http and https.
Thereby to avoid security warnings, we load it over https if we are on https, or http if we are on http.

note:

Unfortunately, you can't do the same thing for google analytics.

they use the domains `ssl.google-analytics.com` and `www.google-analytics.com` for https and http.