# // used instead of http:// on src="" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shorthand  as // for script and link tags? anyone see / use this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before)

I think I understand what is going on but I haven't found anything definitive while googling. In code such as this:

```
// talking about the src attribute
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/%kitid%.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am used to http:// being there. When I call this page on an http server it makes a regular HTTP request for the resource so I am assuming this is a shortcut for http://. I am guessing this has to do with not knowing whether the page you are on wants to use https:// or http://? Any articles or anything that have some information on this practice?

Comment: That is called a "protocol-relative URL".  It will use the protocol that the parent page was requested with.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693598/using-instead-of-protocol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799577/does-using-www-example-com-in-javascript-chose-http-https-protocol-automatical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254646/absolute-paths-beginning-with-two-slashes

Comment: That's the problem with those questions : you know how to call the object only when you have the answer...

Comment: Or just search for "double slash" or "two slashes" if you don't know @dys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `//`, the request will mimic the protocol from the parent's page.

Have a look at this: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/