# CSS and JS Linking Without The Protocol

Tags: javascript, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace  with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

I've been seeing sites linking to CSS and JS without the protocol more and more often lately:

```
<script src="//domain.cloudfront.net/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And CSS

```
<link href="//domain.cloudfront.net/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is this valid in all browsers? Does leaving off `http` or `https` mean the browser intelligently decides which protocol to use?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693598/using-instead-of-protocol), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799577/does-using-www-example-com-in-javascript-chose-http-https-protocol-automatical), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before) and probably more than a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Paul Irish has a good blog entry about this. http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

It's basic purpose is to prevent those IE pop ups that warn you that some of the resources on the page are "non-secure" when your main protocol is https but you grab something with http.

Comment: I'd hope that people use it so that they don't introduce security problems rather then to prevent browsers warning their visitors about those security problems!

Comment: Ha, true. That's an epically long debate reserved for quora or something.

Comment: Apparently it causes IE 7/8 to [double-download CSS files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2975722/283366)