# Why is there two slashes in front of the layout string in yii?

Tags: php, yii

When I create a new Yii application using the `yii webapp [my_application]` command, it creates a folder with a bunch of files and folders in it. One of those files is the Controller component which extends the CController. Inside the Controller class, the `layout` property is declared as such:

```
public $layout='//layouts/column1';
```

My question is: Why is there two slashes in front of the layout string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two slashes refer to the views root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it uses XML/XPath internally and an xpath starting with `//` is simply an absolute path.

The `$layout` XPath in your code would select the `<column1>` descendants of the top-level `<layouts>` elements.

Comment: It does not use XPath, it just recognizes `//` as a root path. It also does not refer to document path, it's simply alias to filesystem path.

Comment: `//` in XPath is almost the *opposite* of an absolute path - it would match *any* node with the given name, however deep in the tree. An absolute path would only have a single leading `/`, to signify direct children of the root node, rather than "any descendent".