# Meaning of (./) in URI?

Tags: http, url, uri

After reading and seeing the samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4071178/859154)

Given the example of uri :

```
 http://a/b/c/d;p?q
```

redirecting to `"g"` will redirect me to  `http://a/b/c/g` ( cause c is the directory)

So I ask myself when should i use `./g`

It is actually the same [goto current folder and find `g`]

so Why this syntax is even exists ? `./` when should I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put it this way:

There is no special reason why this construct exists (or was created/defined). It simply exists because it is a logical combination of other constructions (`.`, `/`,`/g`) that are required and thus defined out of other reasons. Since those constructions (path components here) can be combined more or less without limitation the questionable constrcut `./g` is well defined and thus valid. But that does not mean that there must be special reason why exactly this construct was or has to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
   components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
   fragment.

```
  URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

  hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
```

The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
   empty (no characters).  When authority is present, the path must
   either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.  When
   authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash
   characters ("//").  These restrictions result in five different ABNF
   rules for a path (Section 3.3), only one of which will match any
   given URI reference.

```
  The following are two example URIs and their component parts:

         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
          |   _____________________|__
         / \ /                        \
         urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

Comment: i dont understand how this answer my question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir i was not  sure that why i make cw ...could you please add the correct answer i am sure i have got complete knowledge about your question

Comment: It doesn't tell when/ why should I use `./` it just show the structure.... am I wrong ?