# How to load the url in html div tag using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here the below i have wriiten for load the webpage inside of div tag via 'url' i've enclosed. but it not working. can anyone know. pls help.

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="lurl();">Click Here</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><div id="durl">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function lurl(){
$('#durl').load('http://www.tndte.com/Result/');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: R u getting any errors? That URL returns any data at all?

Comment: is it the external url?

Comment: ya its a proper url only.. if i using iframe it return the proper output, but iframe restrict something to access. but above pgm return nothing. i cant find the error also.

Comment: If it's an external web site there's no going around the access restrictions using JavaScript only.

Comment: you would need to create a proxy that would run server side.

Answer (score 1):

you can’t use jQuerys ajax methods to fetch data from external domains without using a `Proxy, YQL, JSONP` or equivalent technique to get around this. Browser restricts, most Ajax requests are subject to the "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".

You can use the https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js and include the js file in your page. Below is the function that I used to load the external page.

```
function test () {
         $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.tndte.com/Result/',
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(res) {
             var content = $(res.responseText).text();
             alert(content);
           }
         });
       }
```

Comment: @user1709672 have you included the xdomainajax.js?

Answer (score 1):

Thats correct, ajax calls cannot retrieve external pages for security reasons.

The only way to get external pages onto your page is to use an iframe, or a simple server side proxy that you can call with your ajax.

We can not do that unless the content are coming from the same domain , and reason javaScript's Same Origin Policy.

You can still do it as

1. use iframe load the content
2. use server-side script

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are accessing files on the same server as your page is, this will not work.
You need to use an iframe if you're trying to embed external content.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Comment: Or you could use PHP's `include()` or `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

Before trying out the answers..You have to add http: in your src path.

Comment: It's not necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave

Comment: @Juhana Good catch. I have tried with this syntax its throwing error - ReferenceError: $ is not defined