# Save To Drive Button Doesn't Work

Tags: google-drive-api

I wrote a simple file server in NodeJS to serve a HTML page with a Save To Drive button. HTML page is served at `my_address:1337` and file to be saved is served at `my_address:1338`. Upon clicking the Save To Drive button, it shows "Starting Download" for a long time then displays `Failed Download. XHR Error`.

I thought this was due to the fact that the file was being served from a different port so I decided to do the same with an appengine app. Page served at http://sayodrive.appspot.com/index.html and file served at http://sayodrive.appspot.com/drivefile.jsp, I got the same problem.

Then I decided to do a local Java web application: same problem. Then I tried changing the content disposition to `attachment` (to force a download) but didn't work either.

Frustrated, I started Googling and came across [this page](http://jsbin.com/okoseq/3) that claims the Save To Drive button doesn't actually work.
So I went back to the [official Google Drive SDK page](https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive) and discovered that their example button doesn't work too. **Is this a bad dream?**

SOURCE: index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test: Save To Drive</title>
    <!--  -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://sayodrive.appspot.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This must be the worst HTML you have ever seen :)</p>
    <div class="g-savetodrive"
       data-src="//http://sayodrive.appspot.com/drivefile.jsp"
       data-filename="Test Drive"
       data-sitename="Sayo Saves">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

SOURCE: drivefile.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DriveFile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%
      java.io.Writer w = response.getWriter();
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      w.write("If you're reading this in Drive, congrats!");
      w.flush();
      w.close();
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the report, Google are investigating this as fastly as possible.

Comment: The demo here works, https://googledrive.com/host/0BxSeRWWA9m3mcU4zSzFzREZScVk/buttonSimple.html

Comment: Google are investigating the documentation button separately.

Comment: Can you check your data-src ?

Comment: Your example works. The only difference between your example and what's on the official example is the data-src format (the leading `//` in the official example).

Comment: Just as Ali said, your data-src seems to be incorrect. it should be `data-src="//sayodrive.appspot.com/drivefile.jsp"`

Comment: Enable CORS https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive#cors on your server and use `data-src="//sayodrive.appspot.com/drivefile.jsp"` as others say. To learn more about double slashes, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave

Comment: data-src="drivefile.jsp" works and I think that should suffice. Thanks guys!

Comment: @AliAfshar any explanation for why the official example didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The original sample was not working because the `Cache-Control` header was not being exposed by the server. This is now fixed.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
```

More in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive#cors).