# Google Drive's save to drive with Laravel?

Tags: google-drive-api, filepath

I'm trying to use the "Save to drive" button that Google provides to make Drive uploads even easier, it looks like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

My question is, since I am using Laravel and the `php artisan serve` command to serve my project, how am I supposed to write the path to my file? It's located at 'Project name'/storage/app/docs/, I've tried `//storage/app/docs/{{ $file->path }}` but it doesn't work, and using storage_path() didn't change anything. What am I missing here?

EDIT: 
I tried using another file, one that was hosted somewhere else. So I enabled CORS on my project and, using Postman, I tested to see the headers I was using:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Range

Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*

Access-Control-Expose-Headers →Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
```

According to the Google documentation, it should be working now, yet it's not.
This is the error that I'm getting in the console:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

And I'm oficially out of ideas.

Comment: `//` in `//example.com/.....` is just short for "whatever protocol is being used right now". See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9646435/605707) for more info.

Comment: I understand now, but still, I used Laravel's `asset()` function (which is supposed to resolve the scheme of requests automatically) and it still doesn't work, I just get a "Failed Download XHR error"

Comment: Regardless of how `asset()` behaves, you cannot point at files outside the web root from within your HTML. The browser can only make requests to stuff within your Laravel app's public/ folder. Read **The Public Disk** section [in these docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration) to learn more about how your `storage/app/docs/` directory should probably be symlinked to `public/`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the document - [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#troubleshooting),

> If you get an XHR error when downloading your data-src URL, verify that the resource actually exists, and that you do not have a [CORS](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#cors) issue.
>
> If the Save to Drive button works with all browsers except Internet Explorer 9, you may need to configure your browser to enable [CORS](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#cors), which is disabled by default.
>
> If large files are truncated to 2MB, it is likely that your server is not exposing Content-Range, likely a [CORS](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#cors) issue.

Take note the answer on the related SO question - [Save To Drive Button Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726122/5995040) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#cors) that:

> The **`data-src`** URL can be served from another domain but the responses from the HTTP server needs to support HTTP OPTION requests and include the following special HTTP headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
```