# Just got a SSL certificate but there is still a insecure localhost image

Tags: http, ssl, https, mixed-content

I just got an SSL certificate and everything went smoothly except there is still one image that is loading insecurely over http://. It's from a localhost url and I have no idea where it is coming from and how to get rid of it. This is the url that is still loading over http, http://localhost/Proiecte/GIT/kleo/wp-content/uploads/.

My website is https://thenoteshack.com/ if you want to check the error console.

Any advice on how I can convert this to https or just get rid of it? I have no clue what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insecure reference is in the div id="rev_slider_1_1", value for CSS property background-image:url.

```
<div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" style="padding:0px;">
<!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.93 fullscreen mode -->
    <div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" style="display:none;background-image:url(http://localhost/Proiecte/GIT/kleo/wp-content/uploads/);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-fit:cover;background-position:center top;">
<ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->
```

Comment: This solves it by using full url (protocol + domain name + path). How to do this when running on localhost and running on a production server which of course has different domain names (or ports)?

Comment: You can use the protocol relative URL if you do not have a fixed protocol e.g., //somedomain/somepath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave. As for different domain names, my guess is that you'll need to use a programming language like PHP to specify the value of the domain using some variable.