# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when accessing webpage address starting from www. Without www it works - why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a webservice in my node.js web app (placed on amazon ec2) and it takes email address and saves it to mongodb. This webservice is placed on `/mail` of my server.
I wrote a small ajax code that sends the data directly to the webservice. 
It looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://example.com/mail',
     type: "POST",
     data: {
         email: $('input[name=subscribe_email]').val()
     },
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(response)
         {
             var output = '<p style="color: white">Thanks, we will be in touch!</p>';
             form.find("#form_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
         }
});
```

When in browser I enter my page by typing http://example.com and provide email - everything works fine. But when I add `www` and enter my webpage as www.example.com - then after trying to send email I'm getting a well known error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/mail. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I change my ajax code (or any other possible parts of code) so that I can submit email either from `http://` or `www` pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access control rules consider the URL method ("http" or "https"), the whole domain name, and the port number.  The rules don't "think" about the URL; it's a straight textual comparison.

Thus, "www.example.com" and "example.com" are considered two distinct domains, and so cross-origin rules apply.

You can use the URL `"/mail"` in your `$.ajax()` call instead, which will use the same method and domain and port as the containing page.

(Edited - I was confused or undercaffeinated or both. Should be "/mail" with one slash.)

Comment: I changed `http://example.com/mail` to `//mail` and now I'm getting error: `jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 POST http://mail/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @charlietfl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave

Comment: @user3766930 sorry charlietfl is correct; I'll edit the answer.