# Script tag with scheme-less URI generates file not found error on publish

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2019

It seems the recommendation is to use the scheme-less URIs then you can never trigger the mixed mode error in browsers but it doesn't seem possible to get a site to publish in Visual Studio 2019 if there are references to scheme-less URIs in _Layout.cshtml.

This code includes jQuery:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

But trying to publish the site fails with this error:

```
Warning TS6053  (JS) File '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js' not found.
```

If I add `https:` before the `//` then it publishes correctly.
Is this a bug or are schemeless URIs not recommended? Looking online it seems browsers as far back as IE3 support this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the error was just Visual Studio being flaky as the forth time I closed and re-opened it (adding `https:` back and saving and building, then closing, then re-opening and removing `https:` again then building and publishing), it no longer had issues with the scheme-less URIs and published successfully.

Comment: Not to be picky.. But // is not only scheme independent, but *also* protocol independent - which basically states: "get whatever you can"... so it could be it's not VS acting up, but browser / OS related (edit: also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave )

Comment: Thanks I suppose it's possible but it hasn't minded me using it since and it was on the latest version of Windows and VS 2019. I think it just wanted to mess with me that day!