# How to get the full link using BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The function `get("href")` is not returning the full link. In the html file exist the link:

[image]

But, the function `link.get("href")` return:

> "navhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO"

```
sub_site = "https://www.fotoregistro.com.br/navhome.php?vitrine-produto-slim"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(sub_site)

data = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):

    url = link.get("href")
    print (url)
```

Comment: I don`t see any similar link on the [page](https://www.fotoregistro.com.br/navhome.php?vitrine-produto-slim) that you are trying to scrap.

Answer (score 0):

Let me focus on the specific part of your problem in the html:

```
<a class='warp_lightbox' title='Comprar' href='//www.fotoregistro.com.br/
navhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO'><img src='
//sh.digipix.com.br/subhomes/_lojas_consumer/paginas/fotolivro/img/180slim/vitrine/classic_01_tb.jpg' alt='slim' />
                              </a>
```

You can get it by doing:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'warp_lightbox'}):
    url = link.get("href")
    break
```

you find out that `url` is:

```
'//www.fotoregistro.com.br/\rnavhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO'
```

You can see two important patterns at the begininning of the string:

- `//` which is a way to keep the current protocol, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave);
- `\r` which is ASCII Carriage Return (CR).

When you print it, you simply lose this part:

```
//www.fotoregistro.com.br/\r
```

If you need the raw string, you can use [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) in your `for` loop:

```
print(repr(url))
```

and you get:

```
//www.fotoregistro.com.br/\rnavhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO
```

If you need the path, you can replace the initial part:

```
base = 'www.fotoregistro.com.br/'

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'warp_lightbox'}):
    url = link.get("href").replace('//www.fotoregistro.com.br/\r',base)
    print(url)
```

and you get:

```
www.fotoregistro.com.br/navhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO
www.fotoregistro.com.br/navhome.php?lightbox&dpxshig=/iprop_prod=180-slim/tipo=fotolivro/width=950/height=615/control=true/tema=tema_02/preview=true/nome_tema=Q2wmYWFjdXRlO3NzaWNvIFByZXRv&cpmdsc=MOZAO
.
.
.
```

---

Without specifying the class:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = link.get("href")
    print(repr(url))
```

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution, where without knowing the classes I can collect all available links

Answer (score 0):

Use select and seems to print fine

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.fotoregistro.com.br/fotolivros/180-slim?cpmdsc=MOZAO')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([item['href'] for item in soup.select('.warp_lightbox')])
```

---

Use

```
print([item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href]')])
```

for all links.

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution, where without knowing the classes I can collect all available links.

Comment: then use print([item['href'] for item in soup.select('a')])

Comment: this way i have:
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: See edit above now  print([item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href]')])